# How to find and replace a jar file using find command

Tags: bash, unix

I have multiple sub directories under a base directory. I need to copy few jar files available in another path if the sub directory have x.jar .

I am using below command to find x.jar and after that I am trying to copy the jar files.

```
find . -type f -name x.jar | xargs cp /home/sampath.anisetti/tmp/*.jar
```

I am getting `cp: target ./test3/x.jar` is not a directory.

Kindly suggest.

NOTE: If the sub directory don't have x.jar that directory need to skip while copying.

Comment: Do you have gnu find ?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
find . -type f -name x.jar -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d'' file; do
        cp -- /home/sampath.anisetti/tmp/*.jar "$(dirname -- "$file")"
    done
```

It will find all files called `x.jar` and then for each such file, it will find the directory where that file resides, and copy there all the other `*.jar` files.

Comment: Can you explain the signature usage of `--` flag in `cp` ?

Comment: @Inian That's just some standard precaution that I include in all of my scripts. It ensures that `cp` (or `dirname`) will not treat the filename as a command line flag if it starts with a `-`.

Comment: Could avoid the usage of sub-shell, using a `process-substitution`, like `done <(find ...)` may be. Just an optimization procedure, otherwise `+1`

Comment: @123: remember reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 here sometime back, maybe I was wrong. So process substitution runs everything on the sub-shell and the local environment is not used at all?

Comment: @Inian The command is run in the subshell instead of the loop in proc sub, instead of the other way round when piping. it allows you to keep variables.

Comment: @redneb thanks for the reply can you explain dirname statnds for

Comment: @sampath It strips off everything after the last `/`. Would be more efficient to use `"${file%/*}"`

Comment: @sampath `dirname` extracts the directory from the path of a file, e.g. `dirname /foo/bar/file.txt` returns `/foo/bar`.

Comment: @redneb it literally just removes everything after the last `/`, it has no concept of files or directories. The only difference is if there isn't a / it outputs `.`

Comment: @123 Yes you right, I was going for the simplest explanation.